# Inequality $\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{b^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1}\geqslant\sqrt{6(a+b+c)}$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the following inequality for nonnegative real numbers $a,b$ and $c$:

$\sqrt{a^2+1}+\sqrt{b^2+1}+\sqrt{c^2+1}\geqslant\sqrt{6(a+b+c)}$

At first glance, AM-GM looks like a good way forward, but I cannot seem to find a place to apply it. Can anyone help?

Comment: what Kind of numbers are $$a,b,c$$?

Comment: Read the first sentence

Comment: ok i have found it ,thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Jensen's Inequality on the convex function $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + 1}$. Then we have:

$$\sqrt{a^2 + 1} + \sqrt{b^2 + 1} + \sqrt{c^2 + 1} \ge \sqrt{(a+b+c)^2 + 9}$$

Now it's enough to prove that $(a+b+c)^2 + 9 \ge 6(a+b+c)$, which is equivalent to $(a+b+c-3)^2 \ge 0$. Hence the proof.

Obviously the equality is obtained at $a=b=c=1$

Comment: oh i'm beaten i have had the same idea

Comment: $$f''(x)=\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

By C-S and AM-GM
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{a^2+1}=\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(a^2+1+2\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1))}}\geq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(a^2+1+2(ab+1))}=$$
$$=\sqrt{(a+b+c)^2+9}\geq\sqrt{6(a+b+c)}.$$
Done!

Comment: A good solution! It was the C-S that I was missing!